# How can I "Connect" 2 classes

Tags: java, class, instantiation

I've seen this, yet I'm a student and In my case I'm pretty confused. I want to make an instance of a blueprint class (`Circle`) in an other Demo class `CircleDemo`.

The code below is the Circle class, and the one below this one is the actual display.

```
public class Circle {
    private double radius;

    public double getRadius(double rad) {
        return radius = rad;
    }
    public double setRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
    public double getDiamiter() {
        return (radius+radius);
    }
    public double getArea() {
        return Math.PI * (Math.pow(radius, 2));
    }
    public double getCircum(){
        return  Math.PI * (radius+radius);
    }
}
```

Display Below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CircleDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Multi Circle Calc");
        System.out.println("===================");
        System.out.print("Enter your radius please ==> ");
        //a scanner statement should be here!
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your'e asking for here.  Do you not know how to create a new instance of a class?

Comment: @azurefrog Yes, i do not :(

Comment: Circle circle = new Circle(); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are confused on how to instantiate a class. Instead of solving your homework for you, let me give you an example.

Say I have the class bellow

```
public class Foo {
    private int data;

    public int getData() {
        return data;l
    } 

    public void setData(int newData) {
        data = newData;
    }
}
```

If I want to create an instance of this class I have to use the new keyword.

```
public class FooDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
    }
}
```

If I want to set the field I can call the setter I created

```
public class FooDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setData(2);
    }
}
```

If I want to query that data I can use the getter

```
public class FooDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setData(2);
        System.out.println(foo.getData());
    }
}
```

Which will print

```
2
```

Each instance holds its own data, so I can easily create multiple instances of `Foo` that each keep their own data

```
public class FooDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo1 = new Foo();
        Foo foo2 = new Foo();
        foo1.setData(3);
        foo2.setData(4);
        System.out.println(foo1.getData());
        System.out.println(foo2.getData());
    }
}
```

Which will print

```
3
4
```

---

In you homework you are assigned with using a `Scanner` to get data from the user and pass it to a setter. You will perform a similar task of instantiating the  `Circle` class and calling setter then calling a different method to view the data. Hopefully the above examples are enough to get you started.

Comment: Ah ok, I Understand what I was confused in. Thank you for the great examples!

Comment: @xJames If you felt this answered your question, you should upvote it, and accept it when that option becomes available.